# line after IFRAME is not visible

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

line after IFRAME is not visible in both IE and FF. refer the below code and let me know whether I am doing anything wrong.

```
<html>
<body>
line before iframe <br />
<iframe src="about:blank" />
<br /> line after iframe
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you need to close the iframe tag.  otherwise the content that comes after it is considered "things to show" when iframe is not supported.

(by the way, i think if you use XHTML to write the <iframe ... />  then IE will take it as HTML instead.  IE doesn't understand XHTML as XHTML. It understands it as HTML.)

Comment: Yes it works after I put separate end tag. I thought both self end and separate end tag are same, I believe it is applicable for all elements. why it is not working with IFRAME, Is there any W3C standard/documentation for this?

Comment: In other words, you can't use the self closing version of the tag.  I hit this myself today.  I'm glad I found this question.

Answer (score 7):

create the iframe with a separate close tag:

```
<html>
<body>
line before iframe <br />
<iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
<br /> line after iframe
</body>
</html>
```

There are some tags (iframe and textarea come to mind) which don't like it when you use their compact form.

Comment: yes it works. what is the reason behind this? Is there any W3C standard for this?

Answer (score 3):

I was integrating Facebook Connect in my webpage via iFrame tag, like this:

```
<iframe src="..." style="..."></iframe>
```

**It worked in all browsers except IE8.**

Now I found out, that **YOU HAVE to provide a text** as content of the tags. Then it works perfectly!

Example:

```
<iframe src="..." style="...">Your browser does not support iFrames</iframe>
```

or what I am using now is the following (display just a space):

**Solution:**

```
<iframe src="..." style="...">&#160;</iframe>
```

Comment: Had the same in IE 11 (11.165.17134.0, Updateversion 11.0.75). Unbelievable!