# Bootstrap : Can i make another page be a modal ? [playframework]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, view, playframework, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a page be a modal when I click the link above, but I have problems doin' that.

> This is the link that should open my modal page :

```
        <a href="@routes.Application.areaDescription(id)" data-toggle="modal">
           Description
        </a>
```

> And this is the template I want to be the modal (my Main page contains just some css and scripts that I am importing) :

```
@(k:String)
@Main("Add description"){

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Area Descritpion</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
       <iframe src="@routes.Application.areaDescription(k)" />

        <form action="@routes.Application.PostAreaDescription(k)" method="POST">
            Area Description :<br>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" name="textarea"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
            <button class="btn">skip</button>
        </form>

    </div><!--modal-body-->

    </div><!--modal-content-->

  </div><!--modal-dialog-->
</div><!--modal fade-->
}
```

I keep getting an empty page ... not a modal ... just an empty page.
Can someone tell me what I am doin' wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You dint close iframe tag `</iframe>` this is why content after iframe is not visible.See [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923328/line-after-iframe-is-not-visible)

You also dint define `data-target` in link to call that particular modal

```
 <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
           Description
        </a>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cf7mpyvv/2/)